# Find the following limit such that n is a big number

Tags: calculus

Suppose $n$ is a big and fixed number (for example $n=23^{75}$).Also suppose $k\geqslant n$.

Find the following limit:$$\lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{\sum_{i=0}^{n} (-1)^i { n\choose i}(n-i)^k}{n^k}=?$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Rewrite your expression as
\begin{align}
\sum^n_{i=0}(-1)^i\binom{n}{i}\frac{(n-i)^k}{n^k}=\sum^n_{i=0} (-1)^i\binom{n}{i}\left( 1-\frac{i}{n}\right)^k.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{i=0}^{n}(-1)^i{n\choose i}(n-i)^k}{n^k}=\lim_{k\to\infty}\sum^n_{i=0}(-1)^i{n\choose i}\left(1-\frac{i}{n}\right)^k$$

$$=\sum^n_{i=0}(-1)^i{n\choose i}\lim_{k\to\infty}\left(1-\frac{i}{n}\right)^k$$

For all $i>0$ we have $1-\frac{i}{n}<1$ so that $\lim_{k\to\infty}(1-\frac{i}{n})^k=0$

So all the terms of the sum disappear except for the $i=0$ term.

So the limit then becomes $(-1)^0{n \choose 0}=1$.

Note: The size of $n$ is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

We have that
$$\frac{\sum_{i=0}^{n} (-1)^i { n\choose i}(n-i)^k}{n^k}=\frac{\sum_{i=0}^{n} (-1)^{n-i} { n\choose n-i}(i)^k}{n^k}=
\sum_{i=0}^{n} (-1)^{n-i} { n\choose i}\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)^k\\
=1+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (-1)^{n-i} { n\choose i}\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)^k\to 1$$
as $k\to+\infty$, because $\displaystyle \lim_{k\to\infty} x^k=0$ for $|x|<1$.